# Post method works 100% locally, but only about 30% in production. Only get http 400 errors in client

Tags: c#, .net, http

I'm really stumped on how to debug this, any help is greatly appreciated! I'm working all in dotnet/C#.

I have a leaflet map on my page, and if a user clicks on a marker representing an airport they get a button popup that will send a POST request to the server. It works flawlessly on my local machine but is very hit or miss in production. I only get 400 error  in the server log, there is no additional information. Using the chrome inspector I don't see anything with the way the form is being rendered that would cause a problem. Could it be some kind of CORS issue??

The form:

```
var circleMarker = L.circleMarker(latlng).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup(airports[i].ident + "</br>" +
                "<form method='post'>" +
                    "<input type='hidden' name='newloc' value='" + airports[i].airport_id + "' />" +
                    '@Html.AntiForgeryToken()' +
                    "<input type='submit' value='Move to Location' name='teleport'></input></form>");
```

The handler in the backend:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync([Bind("id")] Job job, IFormCollection form, string selectjob, string teleport)
{
    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectjob)) 
    {
        user.current_job = _context.Job.Where(j => j.id == job.id).First();
        await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(teleport))
    {
        user.Location = Int32.Parse(form["newloc"]);
        await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
    }
    return RedirectToPage("./Dashboard");
}
```

This is how the html for the form is rendering:

```
<form method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="newloc" value="17302">
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="CfDJ8OoeUjhqYOBItKQtRChxbUpYINiLWHuPop-RRcULHf5ufX7TwaYDL-n0e616JwgKaFvoKBkMdpB-x8d0O1t4wRwtQwOmuQmXbrRzLhSHqXk7p89PcMqw6fRHMnOzSdeaPnLKqtJX2W2HIi27gdk4OPf1lvWrYf6BMo3vwj_BIfyTd47riV3bMVQqrhhgkfF--w">
<input type="submit" value="Move to Location" name="teleport">
</form>
```

For the life of me I can't figure out why it would give me a 400 error sometimes, but not everytime!

Payload from a failed request:

```
newloc: 17302
__RequestVerificationToken: CfDJ8PWE3AZ4v3JCjpPeI7CNjot20zZi9doxfgnx-V4oajQTujWMypvxHwW7REtc_eL_dnxh6eqYdtbdhvckN-HZIgYtCoYbWsGJJ-_bl-tkfMIExLd-ylnmJfCTpAJxWTz1-QYy2Y2n8uy9rfFumDmVFYHvy2rZGCuQ_NDd-QABR2Ja3qoOPuV37HamjAurMG7GQw
teleport: Move to Location
```

Network tab of the dev tools:
[image]

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem when running the browser developer tools?  If so, what do they say?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem locally at all. The browsers developer tools don't tell me anything other than there is a 400 response.

Comment: But a 400 should be a bad request and the tools could tell you if it's actually the form sending bad data or something else.  But non-reproducibility makes that a bit harder.

Comment: Yeah that's been the biggest problem. I'll update my post with what I see in the developer tools but I don't see anything in there that suggests what the problem might be.

Comment: In addition to the IIS logs you should also look at the [HTTPERR](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/how-to-troubleshoot-http-400-errors/ba-p/347601) log.  You could also temporarily disable [Request Verification](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/security/request-verification) for that endpoint to see if that is the cause of your 400 errors.